# Applying Python logging filter

Tags: python

I created a logging filter for my error messages that sets an environment variable.  However, when I apply the filter to my logger it stops printing my error messages to the terminal/writing them to my logging file.

Filter looks like this:

```
class ErrorFilter(logging.Filter):
  def __init__(self,level):
    self.level = level

  def filter(self,record):
    if record.levelno == self.level:
        os.environ["ERROR_FLAG"] = "True"
```

Applied like this:

```
logger     = Utils.getLogger() 
logger.addFilter(ErrorFilter(logging.ERROR))
```

If I don't apply the filter then I get the error message printed in my terminal and written to a file, but when I add the filter that stops.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return something from the `filter` method. If you return `0` like values, it will not log anything. If you return a non zero value, it will log the value.

In your case you did not explicitly return anything so it returns `None` which is a non zero value - this is why it's not logging anything. You can change it to the following:

```
class ErrorFilter(logging.Filter):
  def __init__(self,level):
    self.level = level

  def filter(self,record):
    if record.levelno == self.level:
        os.environ["ERROR_FLAG"] = "True"
        return True
```

Comment: To expand a little bit on this answer, functions without an explicit return statement will return `None` by default, which can be evaluated the same as a `0`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, I was actually updating the answer to explain the same thing.